# angular - fail to update array from service

Tags: angularjs

I got a service that contain some contacts (name,phone). The controller has array that contain a reference to the array from the service so for every change on the array all gets updated.

Service:

```
app.service('ContactManagerService', function()
{
    this.Contacts=[];
    ...
    this.AddContact=function(Contact){...};
    this.RemoveContact=function(Contact){...};
    ...
});
```

**First question:** Is this a good approach? Should every controller/directive need to have a direct reference to the original array from the service? I have read a lot about setting up some events from the service to the controllers when the array has been changed, but it sound stupid because the array on the controller will be change anyway (because its the same array) and the ng-repeat will be updated automatically.

**Second problem:** The service has a method that replace the array to new one:

```
this.ReplaceContacts=function(NewContacts)
    {
        this.Contacts=NewContacts;
    });
```

The ng-repeat does not update because the controller still got the old reference to the old array. So a refresh need to be done.

I tried to replace the code to this one so the same array's reference wont change,  but when the the code enter the foreach, this.Contacts array is undefined and the code stops. Why ?!

```
this.ReplaceContacts=function(NewContacts)
        {
            this.Contacts.splice(0, this.Contacts.length); //remove all contacts
            NewContacts.forEach(function (contact, index) 
            {
                this.Contacts.push(contact);//place the new ones
            });
        });
```

The controller code:

```
app.controller("myCtrl",
    function ($scope,ContactManagerService)
    {
        $scope.Contacts = ContactManagerService.Contacts;

        $scope.AddContact= function (Contact1) {
            ContactManagerService.AddContact(Contact1);
        }
        $scope.RemoveContact = function (ContactID) {
            ContactManagerService.RemoveContact(ContactID);
        }
    });
```

I hope everything is clear,
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your controller code please?

Comment: In this.Contacts.push(contact);, this has a different context

Comment: It's correct, but I don't like it. It breaks encapsulation by exposing the service internals everywhere, and encouraging controllers to directly modify the array instead of going through the service methods.

Comment: Okay then what is your suggestion for fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the callback function passed to `forEach` isn't bound to the service instance. So `this`, inside the callback, is not the service.

My advice: avoid `this` like the plague. It's an enormous source of bugs in JavaScript.

Use

```
 var self = this;
```

at the top of the service, and use `self` instead of `this` everywhere.

Or bind the callback function to the service instance:

```
NewContacts.forEach(function (contact, index) {
    ...
}, this);
```

Comment: thanks man but i didnt fully understand what var self = this will do?

Comment: It will assign `this` (the service) to the variable `self`, and this variable will thus point to the service as `this` does. Except that `self` will **always** point to the service, whereas `this` doesn't always, depending on where you use it (like, for example, in a callback function).

Comment: thanks. Any chance you can tell me if the approach on my first question is currect? have not find anything usefull over google.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply push elements to `Contacts` using [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.

```
this.ReplaceContacts=function(NewContacts){
    this.Contacts.splice(0, this.Contacts.length); //remove all contacts
    Array.prototype.push(this.Contacts, NewContacts);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in previous anser, context of `this` in forEach loop is not what you think it is.

A simplification would be to use `Array.prototype.concat()`:

```
var self = this;
self.ReplaceContacts = function (NewContacts) {
    self.Contacts.splice(0, this.Contacts.length); //remove all contacts
    self.Contacts.concat(NewContacts);   
});
```

Comment: First question really depends on use case.

Comment: so in my example is it a good approach? I have not found something usefull in google

Comment: direct reference can be very helpful

Comment: I read that the controller should not get direct access to delete/update/add on any data.

Comment: That's fine, but doesn't mean not using direct reference to array in controller. If add/delete is done in service  the referenced array in controller will still reflect changes